# Creating a popup after a user has been on the site after a specific period of time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, session

I am creating a popup on my site to try get users to sign up for our mailing list.

By including this `php` file in all my pages the pop up will appear when they have been navigating through the site for over a minute.

However, if they stop on one page and don't click through I still want it to pop up without having to change the page or refresh the current page.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['mailing_list_input']) && $_POST['mailing_list_input']!=""){
    $email = $_POST['mailing_list_input'];
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $params = [$email];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mailing_list(email, date_time) VALUES (?,now())";
        $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);

        $date = new DateTime();
        unset($_SESSION['timer']);
        $_SESSION['already_asked'] = $date;
    }else{
        $email_warning = "<div id='warning'>Email address is not valid</div>";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['mailing_list_hide']) && $_POST['mailing_list_hide']=="hide"){
    $date = new DateTime();
    unset($_SESSION['timer']);
    $_SESSION['already_asked'] = $date;
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['timer']) && !isset($_SESSION['already_asked'])){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify("+1 minutes");
    $_SESSION['timer'] = $date;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['timer']) && !isset($_SESSION['already_asked']) && !isset($_COOKIE["customer_login"])){
    $date = new DateTime();
    if($_SESSION['timer'] <= $date){
        echo "<div id='popup'>";
        echo "<form class='mailing_list_form' method='POST' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='mailing_list_hide' name='mailing_list_hide' value='hide'>";
        echo "<button id='mailing_list_close' name='mailing_list_close' onclick='this.form.submit();'>X</button>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<h2>SUBSCRIBE FOR LATEST DISCOUNTS & COMPETITIONS</h2>";
        echo "Stay up to date with our latest products";
        echo "<br /><br />";
        echo "<form class='mailing_list_form' method='POST' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>";
        echo "<input type='text' id='mailing_list_input' name='mailing_list_input' placeholder='Enter your email address here'>";
        echo "<button id='mailing_list_button' name='mailing_list_button' onclick='this.form.submit();'>";
        echo "<img src='media/icons/subscribe_icon.png' alt='subscribe icon' width='15px' height='15px'>";
        echo "</button>";
        echo "</form>";
        if(isset($email_warning)){echo $email_warning;}
        echo "<p>By continuing you agree to the <u><a href='page/Privacy-and-Cookie-Policy'>Privacy and Cookie Policy</a></u>.</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: for that you'd need JavaScript and a call to setTimeout() to then run some JS code which would show the extra content. Speaking personally though, I **hate** popups like that, especially if they cover the whole screen and stop me doing what I was doing. if it pops up small, in the corner, without blocking anything else then fine, but if it gets in the way then it really annoys me and puts me off using the site. More so if the site owner doesn't bother to employ any way of detecting whether they've shown me the same popup 10 times already.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your comment, yeah I had thought of doing it in JS but I wanted the timer to be persistent across pages rather than starting the timer again each time they went to a new page and wasn't sure how I could do this

Comment: it's harder. You could perhaps employ a manual countdown and save it in sessionStorage every time they leave a page, and then fetch it each time a page loads. I certainly wouldn't attempt to do anything server-side. And maybe use cookies to see if the user has seen it before, and either dismissed it several times, or already signed up.

Comment: @ADyson, yeah I hate them too but i'm just the lowly programmer doing what I'm told unfortunately. But it's definitely going to be down in the bottom corner as small as I can make it

Comment: You could use ajax (and JS) and check against a store date/time. I'm thinking out loud here of course.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for your comment, yeah I was thinking something similar like storing the date/time in sql when a new visitor arrived and then doing an ajax call to see if the time has passed since then but i'd have to do an ajax call after every couple of seconds and didn't think that would be very efficient

Comment: Welcome. No need to check at every second. Soon as they click to the next page, your ajax call (should) check for the timestamp, theoretically that is.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yeah so as it is now, it will happen if they go through to the next page, I want it to happen if they stall on the page without clicking through but I want the timer to be persistent from the first page they landed on.

Comment: Oh right. Ok, well I'm not a JS guy. Someone provided an answer below, see that. You could reset the timer on each page view and then re-check on next page load. I couldn't write this fast but if I needed to, I guess I could figure it out. Sorry I couldn't be of any more help on this.

Comment: I think I'm going to need to do a combination of all of these things like setting a JS timer and saving where it was in a session when they leave a page to be picked up and continued on the next page like @ADyson suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I came up with in the end. If they are navigating through the site it will get the session timer and if the stall on the page without clicking through it will just use a JS timer

```
<script>
    function displayPopup(){
        $("#popup").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    function hidePopup(){
        $("#popup").css("display", "none");
    }
</script>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mailing_list_input']) && $_POST['mailing_list_input']!=""){
    $email = $_POST['mailing_list_input'];
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $params = [$email];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mailing_list(email, date_time) VALUES (?,now())";
        $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);

        $date = new DateTime();
        unset($_SESSION['timer']);
        $_SESSION['already_asked'] = $date;
    }else{
        $email_warning = "<div id='warning'>Email address is not valid</div>";
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['mailing_list_hide']) && $_POST['mailing_list_hide']=="hide"){
    $date = new DateTime();
    unset($_SESSION['timer']);
    $_SESSION['already_asked'] = $date;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['already_asked'])){
    echo "<script>var popup_timer = setTimeout(displayPopup, 10000);</script>";
}
?>
<div id='popup'>
<form class='mailing_list_form' method='POST' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>'>
<input type='hidden' id='mailing_list_hide' name='mailing_list_hide' value='hide'>
<button id='mailing_list_close' name='mailing_list_close' onclick='this.form.submit();'>X</button>
</form>
<h2>SUBSCRIBE FOR LATEST DISCOUNTS & COMPETITIONS</h2>
<p>Stay up to date with our latest products</p>
<form class='mailing_list_form' method='POST' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>'>
<input type='text' id='mailing_list_input' name='mailing_list_input' placeholder='Enter your email address here'>
<button id='mailing_list_button' name='mailing_list_button' onclick='this.form.submit();'>
<img src='media/icons/subscribe_icon.png' alt='subscribe icon' width='15px' height='15px'>
</button>
</form>
<?php if(isset($email_warning)){echo $email_warning;} ?>
<p>By continuing you agree to the <u><a href='page/Privacy-and-Cookie-Policy'>Privacy and Cookie Policy</a></u>.</p>
</div>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['timer']) && !isset($_SESSION['already_asked'])){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify("+20 seconds");
    $_SESSION['timer'] = $date;
    echo '<script>hidePopup();</script>';
}
if(isset($_SESSION['timer']) && !isset($_SESSION['already_asked']) && !isset($_COOKIE["customer_login"])){
    $date = new DateTime();
    if($_SESSION['timer'] <= $date){
        echo '<script>displayPopup();</script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script>hidePopup();</script>';
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION['already_asked'])){
    echo '<script>hidePopup();</script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language, (in)activity happens on the client-side. You have to implement you solution on the latter, with JS for example:

```
var popupTimer,
TIME_OUT = 60;

function displayPopup() {
    // display the popup
}

popupTimer = setTimeout(displayPopup, TIME_OUT);

$(document).on('click change keypress', function() {
    clearTimeout(popupTimer);

    // Reset
    popupTimer = setTimeout(displayPopup, TIME_OUT);
});
```

Comment: I do not think this will work for me as hopefully the users will be active and I don't want it to fire after a certain amount of inactivity. I want it to fire when they have been on the site for a specific amount of time no matter what activity they have done like clicking through different pages which with this solution would reset the timer.